# Is there a way to quick-migrate a question from an external forum?

Tags: feature-request, migration

Let's say I post a question on the Microsoft Forum. But I don't get an adequate answer. Is there a way to quick-migrate it to Stackexchange or do I have to recompose it here ?

There should be a framework to unify all web-communities to reduce duplicate information if not for anything else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Um… no.

---

Useless. Can't you just copy-paste? Why do we need an *import tool*? What do you think this is?

To ask a question, you need to:

- Have an on-topic problem
- Try to solve it.
- Try harder to solve it.
- Write it in a way so that we can understand it

  - A clear title
  - Background information
  - The code
  - What you're trying to do
  - Your solution
  - Why it doesn't work
  - Your question (one sentence, on the bottom, with a question mark)

Forum questions almost always never get to step one.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask it at metastackexchange.com. I guess I posted it on the wrong site. but I guess I'd get the same answer there. 

I have seen the same issue being discussed in multiple forums. I just thought it'd be better if there is no duplication.

Comment: [It's fine if users post bug reports, requests for support or feature requests here on MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250152/2888561)